# How to migrate shared database from Access to SQL Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I have been using MS Access databases via DAO for many years, but feel that I ought to embrace newer techniques.

My main application runs on end user PCs (no server) and uses a shared database that is created and updated on-the-fly.  When the application is first run it detects the absence of a database and creates a new empty one.

Any local user running the application is allowed to add or update records in this shared database.  We have a couple of other shared databases, that contain templates, regional information, etc., but these are not updated directly by the application.

Updates of the application are released from time to time and each new update checks the main database version and if necessary executes code to bring the database up to the latest specification.  This may involve the creation or deletion of tables and/or columns.  New copies of the template databases are also included as part of the update.

Our users are not required to be computer-literate and should not need to run any sort of database management software beyond those facilities provided by the application.

It all works very nicely with DAO/Access, but I'm struggling to find how to do it with SQL Express.  The databases seem to be squirrelled away in locations that are user-specific and database creation and update seems at best awkward to do by program code alone.

I came across some references "Xcopy deployment" that looks like it could be promising, but there seem to be references to "user instances" that sound suspiciously like something that's not shared.  I'd appreciate advice from anyone who has done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you haven't fully absorbed *the* fundamental difference between the Access Database Engine (ACE/Jet) and SQL Server:

When your users launch your Access application it connects to the Access Database Engine that has been installed on their machine. Their copy of ACE/Jet opens the shared database file (.accdb or .mdb) in the network folder. The various instances of ACE/Jet work together to manage concurrent updates, record locking, and so on. This is sometimes called a "peer-to-peer" or "shared-file" database architecture.

With an application that uses a SQL Server back-end, the copies of your application on each user's machine connect over the network to the *same* instance of SQL Server (that's why it's called "SQL *Server*"), and that instance of SQL Server manipulates the database (which is stored on its local hard drive) on behalf of all of the clients. This is called "client-server" or "server-based" database architecture.

Note that for a multi-user database you *do not* install SQL *Server* on the client machines, you only install the SQL Server Client components (OleDb and ODBC drivers). SQL Server itself is only installed in one place: the machine that will act as the SQL... Server.

re: "database creation and update seems at best awkward to do by program code alone" -- Not at all, it's just "different". Once again, you pass all of your commands to the SQL Server and *it* takes care of creating the actual database files. For example, once you've connected to the SQL Server if you tell it to

```
CREATE DATABASE NewDatabase
```

it will create the database files (`NewDatabase.mdf` and `NewDatabase_log.LDF`) in whatever local folder it uses to store such things, which is usually something like

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

on the server machine.

Note that your application ***never*** accesses those files directly. In fact it almost certainly *cannot* do so, and indeed your application does not even *care* where those files reside or what they are called. Your app simply talks to the SQL Server (e.g. `ServerName\SQLEXPRESS`) and the server takes care of the details.

Comment: Thanks Gord.  I understood about servers, but some articles I had been reading about SQL Server Express's handling of local files seemed to be suggesting that each user had their own instance that would be stored in a user-specific location.  You're answer has cleared that up nicely for me.  I'll build a little test app to create and populate a database and take it from there.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update on my progress.  Inspired by suggestions here and this article on code project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63147/Handling-database-connections-more-easily,
I've created a wrapper for the ADO.NET methods that looks quite similar to the DAO stuff that I am familiar with.

I have a class that I can use just like a DAO Database.  It wraps ADO methods like ExecuteReader, ExecuteNonQuery, etc. with overloads that can accept a SQL parameter.  This allows me to directly replace DAO Recordsets with readers, OpenRecordset with ExecuteReader and Execute with ExecuteNonQuery.

Each method obtains and releases the connection from its parent class instance.  These in turn open or close the underlying connection as required depending on the transaction state, if any.  So a connection is held open for method calls that are part of a transaction, but closed immediately for a single call.

This has greatly simplified the migration of my program since much of the donkey work can be done by a simple "find and replace".  The remaining issues are then relatively easy to find and sort out.

Thanks, once again to Gord and Maxwell for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is too long to right down... but go to Microsoft page, there they explain how to make it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/move-access-data-to-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-upsizing-wizard-HA010275537.aspx

I hope this help you!!

Comment: Interesting article and some useful information, but I specifically don't want to use UI tools like Wizards.  All this has to be done without end-user intervention, so I'll have to write code to create the new database and then copy the data from the access tables to the SQL tables.  That shouldn't be too difficult as I can use a combination of DAO and ADO.NET in the conversion program.